# scroll animated slideToggle legend to html/body top

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle, legend, fieldset

I click on the `content2` slidetoggle to show the content but I need the html/body to scroll to the # section, moving the opened slidetoggle to the top of the page.
I need the main window to scroll down to that section once clicked.
I have this code but can't work out where to add it:

```
$("html, body").animate({'scrollTop': $(this).offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>
            <a href="javascript: void(0);"onclick="$(this.parentNode).next().slideToggle('slow');$('#content2').trigger('scroll');">content 02</a>
        </legend>[>the content<]
</fieldset>
```

Comment: isn't your last tag should be `</fieldset>`

Comment: sorry, yes it is `</fieldset>`, its not the problem. i just entered it incorrect here. can you help me?

Comment: No dear I'm not HTML/JS expert :(

Comment: What do you want to scroll, the `#content2` or the whole document? And where is the `#content2`? Is it the closest parent of your fieldset?

Comment: yes i need the whole window (html/body) to scroll, like it shows in the 1st code. but i can't add it correctly.

Comment: surely it can't be that hard! (?)